# Efficient way to sort numpy Array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, sorting

I have numpy array :

```
result_np = np.full((5000000,4),999.11)
```

modifying this array with a function and almost %2 of the array changed in random order .

also I am sorting above array after modified. I just need change %2 for sort.

I am sorting with :

```
def Par_Sort(result_np):
    return result_np[result_np[:,1].argsort(kind="mergesort")]
```

Before sending the 5.000.000 big array is there any efficient way to only send change array which only about %2.

Comment: why don't you insert the changes into sorted array?

Comment: I cant the function is not thread safe: numba parallel .